# Make function accept both variable number of arguments, or values in array

Tags: javascript, arguments

In JavaScript, it is pretty easy now to make a function accept a variable number of arguments:

```
function doSomething(...args) {
    args.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}
```

Now it can be called like `doSomething(1, 2, 3)` and all arguments will be available inside the function as array `args`. The output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Now I want to call the function, passing all values in one array, like this:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
doSomething(arr);
```

and have the same result. To do it, I have to use [lodash's `_.flatten`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#flatten) inside the function:

```
doSomething(...args) {
    args = _.flatten(args);
    ...
}
```

Are there better ways to modify my function to do this?

I don't need *any* solution, I already have one. I need good solutions doing exactly what I need, but without third party libraries like Lodash and still elegant. I ask because of curiosity, not because I don't know how to do that at all :-)

Comment: If you know it is an array, use `doSomething(...arr)`.

Comment: @str, it's a useful tip, but not exactly what I need.

Comment: you can use default arguments  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: @Dinesh Can you expand that to an answer?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer check Shakti Phartiyal answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function doSomething (...args) {
  args.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
doSomething.apply(null, arr);
```

Or check if the first argument is an array:

```
function doSomething () {
  let args;
  if (Array.isArray(arguments[0])) {
    args = arguments[0];
  } else {
    args = Array.slice(argument);
  }
  args.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
doSomething.apply(null, arr);
```

This approach however is a bit more verbose and doesn't make use of the spread operator. Also, things like this would not work:

```
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
doSomething.apply(null, arr);
```

Comment: `doSomething.apply(null, arr)` isn't `doSomething(arr)`, but it's interesting approach.

Comment: If I omit `...`, the function won't support a call with arguments passed like `(1, 2, 3)`, with variable number of them.

Comment: Yes you are perfectly right. I didn't think about that when writing the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to flatten *all* arrays but only use one, then the following should do:

```
if (Array.isArray(args[0])) args = args[0];
```

You might also want to check for `args.length == 1` in that case.

But in general, instead of overloading your function to do different things with different numbers or types arguments, it's much easier and safer to provide multiple functions:

```
function doSomething(...args) {
    // implementation
}
function doSomethingArr(arr) {
    return doSomething(...arr);
}
```

or

```
function doSomething(...args) {
    return doSomethingArr(args);
}
function doSomethingArr(arr) {
    // implementation
}
```